# How to add certain rows to a 2D matrix?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

I have a simple 2D matrix like this in MATLAB:

```
A = [34 10;
     23 10;
     64 10];
```

What I need to do is to find `max(A(:,1))`, then `while A(j,1) < max(A(:,1))` add rows like `[A(j,1)+1 10]` to the matrix, so I want to eventually get this:

```
A = [34 10;
     35 10;
     36 10;
     37 10;
       .
       .
       .
     62 10;
     63 10;
     64 10;
       .
     23 10;
     24 10;
     25 10;
       .
       .
       .
     62 10
     63 10
     64 10
       .
     64 10];
```

I have written the following but it does not work:

```
for j = 1:size(A,1)
    while A(j,1) < max(A(:,1))
        A(end+1,:) = [A(j,1)+1 10];
    end
end
```

Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: "I have written the following but it does not work". No

Comment: Give an accurate complete description of what the loop does and why that differs from your desired output. Do not expect other people to run your code to find out what your actual question is. If your problem description is "it does not work", your question is bad 99% of the time.

Comment: if max is not the last row, this pattern keeps continue for rows after the max row?

Comment: Thanks for your constructive comment @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following, for Matlab without loops:

```
my_max = max(A(:,1));
my_arrays = arrayfun(@(x) [x:my_max]', A(:,1), 'uni', 0);
my_expanded_column = cat(1,my_arrays{:});
my_output = [my_expanded_column, 10*ones(size(my_expanded_column))]
```

It first finds the maximum,
Then expands each entry to a range to the maximum,
Then combines all the ranges to one,
Then tacks on the second column of 10's.

Answer (score 1):

Your while-loop gets stuck checking the same element over and over again (because you don't increment anything).

You could instead use a for-loop to count up from each element in `A`'s first column. And make sure you add the rows to a new matrix, otherwise your loop will recursively expand `A` ad infinitum.

For example:

```
B = [];
index = 1; % keeps track of the last element of B

for j = 1:size(A,1)
    for k = A(j,1):max(A(:,1))
        B(index,:) = [k A(j,2)];
        index = index + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Great, now I understand what the issue was, thanks a bunch @frslm